# Setting specific Date for Status Bar Notification

Tags: android, date, notifications, statusbar

I simply want the user to pick a date with an EditText field (or maybe a Datepicker), then the app stores it in an SQLite database. (I am only storing the day of the month, so every month on a specific day--1st, 10th, 22nd, etc--it pops up.) The notification system  comes around and checks for that date and displays a "reminder" notification in the status bar that takes them directly to the app to update certain information when pressed.

Based on the simple tutorial [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html) (in "The Basics" section), is the "when" variable what decides "when" the notification pops up?  And if so, could I just populate that with a date variable that is dynamically generated from a database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The notification system comes around and checks for that date and displays a "reminder" notification in the status bar that takes them directly to the app to update certain information when pressed.

If by "the notification system" you mean "the app that I write", then this is possible. Use `AlarmManager` to schedule an alarm for your designated time(s), routing control to a `BroadcastReceiver` that can create and display your `Notification`.

> Based on the simple tutorial here (tin "The Basics" section), is the "when" variable what decides "when" the notification pops up?

No. It is a timestamp associated with the `Notification` for display purposes (e.g., may appear in the notification drawer).

Comment: This seems to be what I need.  AS far as putting it in action, does this seem like a good place to start at this link?  (http://smartandroidians.blogspot.com/2010/04/alarmmanager-and-notification-in.html)

Comment: @KickingLettuce: That should be OK, though I have not examined it all that closely.

Answer (score 0):

yes Date has a method that will return to you its value as a long value represented in milliseconds since a point in time (same way System.currentTimeinMillis() works)

```
long when = mDate.getTime();
```

Answer (score 0):

No, I think that "when" is supposed to indicate when the event took place.  See [this documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html), search for `setWhen(long when)`.

If you don't want your notification to show up right away, you'll need to set up your own timer, or something, in a long-running service.  If you can keep your service running, take a look at the [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) class, in particular the `postAtTime()` method.

Comment: Using a "long-running service" is inappropriate for "every month on a specific day--1st, 10th, 22nd, etc--it pops up". This is what `AlarmManager` is for.

Comment: Sweet!  Good note - I had never heard of `AlarmManager` before - my excuse is I haven't had to do that.  You should write that up as an answer!